# Cambiar data-precio con jquery this

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas estoy intentando cambiar el valor de data-precio con una función de jquery, pero con (this) par que detecte cual tiene que cambiar, pero no lo consigo.

**Iteración de servicios**

```
@foreach ($order->casa->elementosAdicionales as $item)
  <tr>
    <td class="td_flex">
       <div class="form-check form-check-inline poscheck">
                                                                                    
        <input type="text" name="precioNuevo" id="precioNuevo" value="{{ $item->precio }}" class="inputPrecioServ">
                                                                                    
        <input class="form-check-input checkServicios" type="checkbox" id="{{ $item->id }}" data-precio="{{ $item->precio }}" name="adicionales[]" value="{{ $item->id }}" @if($condicion) checked @endif>
       </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Quiero que el valor que le ponga en el input `precioNuevo` lo ponga en el `data-precio` en el checkbox `.checkServicios`

```
$("input[name='precioNuevo']").on('keyup',function(){
    var dInput = this.value;
    console.log(dInput);
    $(this).find(".checkServicios").attr('data-precio', dInput);
})
```

---

No hay forma de con (this) acceder al siguiente elemento sin ser hijo? o hay forma de convertir esto en padre/hijo ?? Al ser una iteración solo necesito que me cambie el que toca, no todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando el método `next()` de `jQuery` tienes acceso al "hermano" siguiente del elemento que estás modificando.

Te dejo un ejemplo simple sin el uso de ciclos ya que no tengo acceso a tus datos, tú lo debes acoplar a tu proyecto. *Evita el uso de `id` en ciclos, a no ser que este se pueda diferenciar en cada iteración.*

```js
$("input[name='precioNuevo']").on('keyup',function(){
    var dInput = $(this).val();
    console.log(dInput);
    //Usando el método next() ubicas el hermano siguiente al input que estás modificando 
    $(this).next().attr('data-precio', dInput);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td class="td_flex">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline poscheck">
      <input type="text" name="precioNuevo" value="1000" class="inputPrecioServ">
      <input class="form-check-input checkServicios" type="checkbox" id="2540" data-precio="1000" name="adicionales[]" value="2540">
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="td_flex">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline poscheck">
      <input type="text" name="precioNuevo" value="2000" class="inputPrecioServ">
      <input class="form-check-input checkServicios" type="checkbox" id="2541" data-precio="2000" name="adicionales[]" value="2541">
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Genial! Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es simplemente que lo que ingreses en el input cambie el valor en el "data-precio", this hace referencia al input #precioNuevo asi que para que modifique el checkbox no necesita usar this para buscar el checkbox, llamelo directamente, y seria mejor usar el evento input ya que el keyup se activa incluso si la tecla no hace nada.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $("input[name='precioNuevo']").on('input',function(){
            var dInput = this.value;
            console.log(dInput);
            $(".checkServicios").attr('data-precio', dInput);
        })
    });
```

Comment: Buenas y gracias por tu respuesta, pero piensa que estoy en una iteración, esto que me indicas fue donde empece, y en el caso de terner 3 iteraciones me modifica las 3 data-precio @Jhandres187

Comment: No se bien como se hace, pero no se puede acceder al siguiente elemento con `this` algo así `input[name='precioNuevo'] > checkServicios`

Comment: Hola Jhandres187, bienvenido, mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)  y aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!